# Including ng2-bootstrap module causes angular-cli to fail

Tags: angular

I use angular-cli (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) and everything works.

But when I try to load this module (ng2-bootstrap) it fails:

1. I inlcude
   `<script src="node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/build/angular2-bootstrap.js"></script>`
2. and after refresh I see`angular2-bootstrap.js:1Uncaught ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined`

How can I resolve it?

Comment: "It fails" is not a technical description. In what way does it fail?

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you are missing some steps along the way, follow this instruction for a proper integration:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/3rd-party-libs#adding-bootstrap-to-your-project

as it describes you have to install it using:

```
npm install moment ng2-bootstrap --save
```

Add the modules to `vendorNpmFiles` array in **angular-cli-build.js** in the main project directory like this:

```
vendorNpmFiles: [
  //...
  'moment/moment.js',
  'ng2-bootstrap/**/*.js',
]
```

After this step, you have to rebuild the app:

```
ng build
```

Then update the `src/system-config.ts` like this:

```
const Map: any = {
 //...
 'moment': 'vendor/moment/moment.js',
 'ng2-bootstrap': 'vendor/ng2-bootstrap'
}

const packages: any {
 //...
 'moment': { format: 'cjs' },
 'ng2-bootstrap': {
   format: 'cjs'
 }
}
```

Now you should be able to use bootstrap components.